# Do not unfold a pasted folded section in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3

I am working with a 4+ MB file and many sections in it are folded. I want to copy some sections and paste them somewhere else in the file without them unfolding themselves whenever I paste.

The example is easy:

1. Fold some code and copy the folded line
2. Paste anywhere else and it will unfold automatically.

I need for sublime to not unfold the code, if it is unfolded then leave it unfolded. If it is folded, then leave it folded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible currently. Cutting and pasting typically uses the system's clipboard, and since Sublime is a **text** editor, you're just copying and pasting raw text without any metadata like where a fold mark might be. The closest thing I can think of is [this plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/BufferScroll), which tracks some metadata for when you reopen a file, but it doesn't work for copying and pasting. If you know Python and the Sublime API it may be a good starting point, through.

If you want, feel free to open an issue [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/new), I couldn't find anything relevant in the currently-open issues. Please keep in mind that this is a community-run issue tracker, and we generally don't have a good idea as to whether the author takes any of them into consideration when planning new features. But, lacking an official issue tracker and feedback from Jon Skinner, this is the best we've got for now.